# If I have a Stream<Class>, how can I access the classes' inherent information such as variables and arrays?

Tags: java, csv, java-stream

I have a class named Person with the following structure:

```
public class Person {
   public final int num;
   public final String name;
   public final String gender;
   public final int age;

   public Person (int aNum, String aName, String aGender, int anAge){
      this.num = aNum;
      this.name = aName;
      this.gender = aGender;
      this.age = anAge;
   }

   public static Person lineValues(String line) {
      String array = line.split(",");
      int numA = array[0];
      String nameA = array[1];
      String genderA array[2];
      int ageA = array[3];
      return new Person(numA, nameA, genderA, ageA);
   }
}
```

The data for a single Person comes from a line in the csv file named people.csv:

```
| Num | Name   | Gender  |Age  |
| --- | ----   | ------  | --- |
| 1   | Fred   | Male    | 41  |
| 2   | Wilma  | Female  | 36  |
| 3   | Barney | Male    | 38  |
| 4   | Betty  | Female  | 35  |
```

Here is my actual question. I have an interface called People which has a function called getGenderCount. This function should go through a Person object and retrieve a map of the count of each gender.

```
static Function<Stream<Person>,Map<String,Long>> getGenderCount = null;
```

My issue is that I am having trouble understanding the proper syntax of how to stream an entire class object. I have worked with primitive streams beforehand. Performing a split such as `.map(x -> x.split(","))` would not work since that would be of the type String and not Person.

My proposed solution would look like this:

```
e -> e.map(x -> x.split(","))
.skip(1) // skips the title line
.filter(x -> x.length == 4)
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x[2], Collectors.counting()));
```

But it should be mapping a Person object's information.I do not want to change anything I have so far except for the stream operations and syntax. I want to understand how to pull the variables from Person and find them in a Stream.

Comment: *I want to understand how to pull the variables from `Person` and **find** them in a Stream* - What do you mean by that? You have no person objects in your stream, but `String[]`, you have a separate collection of `Person? What are you going to *find*? What is the purpose of your function that expects a stream?

Comment: I mean that I want to have a stream of type Person (Stream<Person>). From this stream, I would like to be able to have functions that go through the CSV file and find me information such as the gender count. The gender count is an indexed portion of the array in Person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to operate on the stream with the usual methods like `map`, `filter` or `foreach` and can then use the standard access operation.

```
Stream<Person> people;
people = ...; // initialize stream with some data

// iterate over stream and access each element
people.forEach(person -> { System.out.println(person.name); });
```

The function `getGenderCount` gets a stream of Person as input and returns a map with the genders and their frequency.

Additionally, in Java a string can not be directly assigned to an int. It needs to be converted.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Person {
    public final int num;
    public final String name;
    public final String gender;
    public final int age;

    public Person(int aNum, String aName, String aGender, int anAge) {
        this.num = aNum;
        this.name = aName;
        this.gender = aGender;
        this.age = anAge;
    }

    public static Person lineValues(String line) {
        String array[] = line.split(",");
        int numA = Integer.parseInt(array[0]);
        String nameA = array[1];
        String genderA = array[2];
        int ageA = Integer.parseInt(array[3]);
        return new Person(numA, nameA, genderA, ageA);
    }

    static Function<Stream<Person>, Map<String, Long>> getGenderCount = people -> {
        return people.collect(Collectors.groupingBy((person -> person.gender), Collectors.counting()));
    };

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Stream<Person> people = Files.lines(Paths.get("people.csv"))
                    .map(line -> { System.out.println(line); return line;}) // just to show input
                    .skip(1) // remove first line
                    .map(line -> line.substring(line.indexOf("|") + 1)) // remove first '|' and in front
                    .map(line -> line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf("|"))) // remove last '|' and behind
                    .map(line -> line.replace(" ", "")) // remove spaces, can cause trouble with spaces within names
                    .map(line -> line.replace("|", ",")) // change pipe symbols into commas
                    .map(line -> Person.lineValues(line)); // transform lines into persons
            Map<String, Long> genderCount = Person.getGenderCount.apply(people);
            System.out.println(genderCount);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

produces

```
$ javac Person.java
$ java Person      
| Num | Name   | Gender | Age|
| 1   | Fred   | Male   | 41 |
| 2   | Wilma  | Female | 36 |
| 3   | Barney | Male   | 38 |
| 4   | Betty  | Female | 35 |
{Male=2, Female=2}
$
```

Comment: He doesn't have a stream of `Person`. Read the question.

Comment: @user207421 The given definition of `static Function<Stream<Person>,Map<String,Long>> getGenderCount = null;` implies a stream of `Person`.

Answer (score 2):

Would this do what you want?

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("people.csv"))
.skip(1)
.map(Person::lineValues) // this method must handle "|" divider chars
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getGender, Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: I don't have a getGender method, it is instead set as one of the array indexes from a line in my read csv file.

Comment: @ErisCacigieri So add one. You need it.

Comment: @user207421 This would go against my description. I want to know how to stream what I already have coded. Person already has what I need, the People Stream is what I am working on