# How do I create a BiFunction stream based off of categories?

Tags: java, list, csv, java-stream, mapping

This is a continuation from one of my previous questions:
[If I have a Stream<Class>, how can I access the classes' inherent information such as variables and arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72049722/if-i-have-a-streamclass-how-can-i-access-the-classes-inherent-information-su)

I have a class named `CavePerson` with the following structure:

```
public class CavePerson {
   public final int num;
   public final String name;
   public final String gender;
   public final int age;

   public CavePerson (int aNum, String aName, String aGender, int anAge){
      this.num = aNum;
      this.name = aName;
      this.gender = aGender;
      this.age = anAge;
   }

   public static CavePerson lineValues(String line) {
      String array = line.split(",");
      int numA = array[0];
      String nameA = array[1];
      String genderA array[2];
      int ageA = array[3];
      return new CavePerson(numA, nameA, genderA, ageA);
   }
}
```

Each line in this cavepeople.csv file is a CavePerson object:

```
| Num | Name   | Gender  |Age  |
| --- | ----   | ------  | --- |
| 1   | Fred   | Male    | 41  |
| 2   | Wilma  | Female  | 36  |
| 3   | Barney | Male    | 38  |
| 4   | Betty  | Female  | 35  |
| 5   | Dino   | Pet     | 4   |
| 6   | BamBam | Male    | 2   |
| 7   | Puss   | Pet     | 1   |
```

I am trying to practice using streams on datasets. I want to use a BiFunction that takes a stream of type `CavePerson` and a `String`.

This `String` is one of the defined genders in a `CavePerson` object. The stream should return a `String[]`, which contains everyone who falls under a specific gender. My expected outcome should look like:

```
EXPECTED OUTCOME
Given a stream of type `CavePerson` and "Male": [Fred, Barney, BamBam]
Given a stream of type `CavePerson` and "Female": [Wilma, Betty]
Given a stream of type `CavePerson` and "Pet": [Dino, Puss]
```

This is the beginning of the code, but I am not exactly sure where to go from here:

```
static BiFunction<Stream<CavePerson>, String, List<String>> getSortedGenders = (e, q) -> List.of(q);

//e.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CavePerson -> CavePerson.gender), Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like you actually need a `BiFunction` at all.  Try writing your code without streams so it's clear what you want.

Comment: I am also confused at what the return-type of the `BiFunction` (`List<String>`) is. If we want a mapping/grouping (e.g. `Male -> [ Fred, Barney, BamBam], Female -> [ Wilma, Betty ], Pet -> [Dino, Puss]`), I'd expect a [`Map<String, List<String>>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) (or something similar) as return-type. The parameter `List<String>` (which I assume holds the categories?) seems also superfluous and could be inferred from the actual dataset.

Comment: Do you know what a `Map` is and how it is used in Java?

Comment: I think so, a map should transform based on a predicate. In my case, I want to map my stream by breaking it up into my defined genders?

Comment: I meant the datastructure [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html), not the  operation [`Stream::map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)), sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a BiFunction is what you need, specially not with a stream as one of the params. Note: once a stream has already been operated upon or closed you can not reuse it again. So once you use the BiFunction to get for example the males you can not use that same stream to get the pets or females. Instead you need to read your file again and again to have a stream where you can apply your BiFunction. Nevertheless if you want to do it with a function something like below should work

```
BiFunction<Stream<CavePerson>, String, String[]> getSortedGenders =
        (e, q) -> e.filter(p -> p.gender.equals(q)).map(p -> p.name).toArray(String[]::new);
```

and use it

```
Stream<CavePerson> personStream = // read your file and get the stream 
String[] males = getSortedGenders.apply(personStream,"Male");

personStream = // read your file again 
String[] females = getSortedGenders.apply(personStream,"Female");
```

I think what you realy want might be a predicate from the discription of your question.

```
Predicate<CavePerson> isMale = cavePerson -> cavePerson.gender.equals("Male");
Predicate<CavePerson> isPet = cavePerson -> cavePerson.gender.equals("Pet");
```

which can be used

```
yourStream.filter(isMale).map(...).collect...
```

Comment: My examples are all single instances, my apologies if that is confusing. The function is asking for both a stream and a string, which in this case is the entire stream and one of the gender strings, which will produce a string array of all CavePeople that have that gender

Answer (score 3):

What it looks like is that you just want

```
stream.collect(
  Collectors.groupingBy(
     person -> person.gender,
     Collectors.mapping(
       person -> person.name,
       Collectors.toList())));
```

which does not involve a `BiFunction`.

Comment: This works, but I would like to understand how to apply a BiFunction to this problem. I am relatively new to streams.

Comment: @ErisCacigieri: There is no way in which a `BiFunction` can do anything useful to solve this problem.  It is the wrong tool to solve this.  It also doesn't do what it sounds like you think it does.

Comment: How might a BiFunction stream operation actually work?

Comment: There is only one function in `Stream` that accepts a `BiFunction`.  Have you looked at its documentation?  (There's really nowhere else that a `BiFunction` would be applicable.)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/class-use/BiFunction.html

Reduce might be what I'm looking for since it would reduce the number of CavePeople in my stream based on a gender predicate

Comment: @ErisCacigieri: That's not really what `reduce` does.  If you have a predicate, you need `filter`.